# Не работает justify-content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

У меня 3 проблемы:

1. Как сделать отступ между button1 и button2? Margin не работает.
2. Элементы класса logo2 не выравниваются по центру.
3. Как сделать, чтобы элементы класса item выводились в 2 строки?
   Заранее спасибо!
   [image: Картинка к вопросам 2,3]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #4a5666;
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
}

.first {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  /*background: gray;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a.button1 {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a.button2 {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#id1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 67px;
  font-weight: 500
}

#id2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 67px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.second {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.logo2 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#lid1 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 4px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background-color: #212121;
}

#lid2 {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <p id="id1">LUIS OUENRIQUE</p>
          <p id="id2">User Expirience/User Interface Expert</p>
          <a href="#" class="button1">KNOW MORE</a>
          <a href="#" class="button2">HIRE ME</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img class="heroIMG" src="hero.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo2">
        <p id="lid1"></p>
        <p id="lid2">SERVICES</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fs.png" alt="fs">
          <p>User Research</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fs.png" alt="fs">
          <p>User Research</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fs.png" alt="fs">
          <p>User Research</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fs.png" alt="fs">
          <p>User Research</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fs.png" alt="fs">
          <p>User Research</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="fs.png" alt="fs">
          <p>User Research</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

С флексами не до конца доработали, добавьте:

```
logo2 {
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}
```